# Why do I sometimes get mangled replies with concurrent NSURLSession requests

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsurlsession

I am working on an OS X (Yosemite) app which downloads two types of csv data (call them type A and type B) from the internet asynchronously using the NSURLSession API .There are multiple requests for each type of csv. Each request is it's own dedicated session wrapped in a custom class. There is one base request class with a  subclass for each type. (In hindsight maybe not an ideal design but irrelevant for my issue I think).

The app is constructed such that each type of csv data is downloaded in a sequential queue. Only one request of each type can be active at a time but both types can occur simultaneously and both use the main thread for delegate callbacks. All of this works fine usually.

The issue I am seeing is that sometimes with heavy traffic I get "cross hearing", i.e. I sometimes get a response back to a type B request that is reported as completed successfully but it contains a number of type B cvs lines and then some type A lines tagged on after - so I sometimes (rarely) get type A data in my type B requests. (or the other way around).

Basically it look like the "switching" logic in Apples API gets confused about which incoming packet belongs to what request/session. The two different request types goes to different URLs but they are related and it may be that they both in the end resolve to the same IP, I am not sure about that. I wonder if there may be something related to the packet headers if they come from the same server that makes it difficult to determine what request they belong to (I'm not good enough at the internet protocols to know if this is a sensible guess). If that is the case then the solution must be to ensure all requests are in one queue so that they cannot be active simultaneously, but I do not want to do that large architecture change before I am confident there is no other workaround.

I looked for similar questions and found this old question  ([Why is my data getting corrupted when I send requests asynchronously in objective c for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459057/why-is-my-data-getting-corrupted-when-i-send-requests-asynchronously-in-objectiv))  which appears to describe the exact same issue but unfortunately it has no answer. Other than that I found nothing similar so I guess I am doing something stupid here but it would be good to know why this issue occurs before I start changing the architecture to fix it.

Has anyone seen this before and know what the cause and workaround is?

I did not include any code as I felt there was no point given it appears to be an architecture issue and if I added code it would need to be a lot. However I will be happy to add whatever you suggest if that helps understand the question.

Edit:

The relevant (I hope) code added below. Note objects are one shot only. The parameters for the request are injected by the init method and the NSURLSession is used for a single task only. Hence the session is invalidated after launch and the NSMutableData array released after parsing of the data.

```
-(BOOL)executeRequest {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *theConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *theSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:theConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.queryURL cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:BSTTIMEOUT];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *theTask = [theSession dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest];
    if(!theTask) {
        return NO;
    }
    [theTask resume];
    [theSession finishTasksAndInvalidate];

    self.internetData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];

    return YES;
 }

 -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.internetData appendData:data];
    return; 
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
        if((error)||(![self parseData]))
        {
            self.internetData = nil;

            if(!error) { 
                NSDictionary *errorDictionary = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Parsing of internet data failed", NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : @"Bad data was found in received buffer"};
                error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain code:EIO userInfo:errorDictionary];
            }
            NSDictionary* ui = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:error forKey:@"Error"];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:[self failNotification] object:self userInfo:ui];  
            return;
        }

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:[self successNotification] object:self];
        return;
 }
```

Comment: Please add some code, especcially the code that handles data receiving (`-connection:didReceiveData:`).

Comment: Update:  I implemented a request queue that can serialise the csv requests such that only one can be active at a time. This appears to resolve my issue and with acceptable performance as the number of requests are not that high or time critical. However the main question (why is this happening?) remains unknown and therefore I do not post this as an answer yet.

Comment: I found the solution finally and posted it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to track down my (stupid) error. For future reference the issue was caused by a failure to realise that the data coming back was not zero terminated.

Most of the data requested in my case is XML and the `NSXMLParser`class wants a `NSData`without extra trailing zeros so that works well.

But the requests which occasionally failed uses a CSV format where the data passes over a `NSString`which is created by `[NSString stringWithUTF8String]` which expects a zero terminated c style string as input. This was the main culprit. Often it worked as it should. Sometimes it failed outright and sometimes it just did a buffer overrun and got some of the previous request data that was in the same memory area. These were the cases I noticed when posting the question.

Thus the solution is to switch to the use of `[[NSString alloc] initWithData: encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` which works with non null-terminated `NSData`buffers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You should not create a new session for each request. This are no sessions anymore. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/):

> With the NSURLSession API, your app creates one or more sessions, each of which coordinates a group of related data transfer tasks. For example, if you are writing a web browser, your app might create one session per tab or window, or one session for interactive use and another session for background downloads. Within each session, your app adds a series of tasks, each of which represents a request for a specific URL (following HTTP redirects if necessary).

Second: Where do you store the session et al., so it is not deallocated?

Your main problem: Obviously you start new requests while requests are potentially running. But you have only one `NSMutableData` instance that receives the data in `-URLSession:task:didReceiveData:`: Many requests, one storage … Of course that mixes up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I do not fully understand what you mean. I was under the impression that NSURLSession was a common way to make  network connections. Could you please clarify. Further I realise I was unclear in my question. Each request is in it's own object instance that holds it's own NSURLSession and also holds the NSMutableData buffer as a property so I do not think that different requests stomp on each others data. These objects are fire once so it is impossible to launch more than one request with each.

Comment: To the first part: See my edit. The second one: Okay, I really did not realize that there is a new instance for every request. However, in such a case I would check at the beginning of `-executeRequest` whether there is already a request in progress or – better –give the instance an initializer that is fully parametrized and execute the request immediatly.

Comment: Thanks, yes I start requests wile others are running, but never in the same NSURLSession. The docs appear to indicate that is the intent, for example they talk about one session per tab in a web browser. Yet for some reason I get responses confused so that I get part of reply thats should go to session A in session B. Still as you say I have worked around the issue by implementing a sequential queue for all objects. Still why the confusion of replies happens remain unclear to me I will investigate if I accidentally may create references to some shared session.

Comment: No, this in not the intend, since one tab has hundreds of requests. I would like to know the reason for this behavior, too, even you found a solution.

Comment: I will keep looking. If I find answer to the question why I will post it. Thanks